# Deserialize with Gson, but App was updated (new Object Structure)

Tags: android, json

How to proper deserialize a Json file, if the App was updated and the object structure changed (e.g. new/deleted variables in an object)? So the saved Object in the Json file is different to the current version of the App.

E.g. i have one class Person

```
public class Person{

    private String name;
    private String city; 
    private int age; //variable was added

    //constructor..

    //getter, setter..
}
```

The class was updated with the new variable `age` but the Json file contains just the two variables `name` and `city`.

Im getting my old Person Object with following code:

```
public static Person fromJsonFile(String path) {
    try (Reader reader = new FileReader(path)) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Person object = (Person)gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
        if (object != null)
            return object;
        else return null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

How is it possible to cast the old Person Object to the new one?

I'v searched for two hours now, but didnt find anything helpful.

Comment: Man, try to read it again. I have read two times but still can't understand your question.

Comment: hey, sorry i thoght it was understandable, i just edited the question, i hope its more clear now?

Comment: If your JSON only has the value of the 2 variables, you can't get the third variable. It would either be `null` or you would have to assign a value to it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any way than, to check for the missing variables? And than assign automatically a value by default? I cant see a solution here, because it would have to be dynamically with x variables with y different types... Or am i wong?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **age**'s type from `primitive` to `object` so that, when the JSON doesn't have any `key` named **age**, `GSON` can assign its value to null.

**Person**

```
public class Person{
    public static final Integer DEFAULT_AGE = -1;

    private String name;
    private String city;
    private Integer age; // change primitive type to object type

    public int getAge() {
        return age == null ? DEFAULT_AGE : age;
    }

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Old app will use the person object as usual. But in the new app, you need to check age before doing any operation

```
Person person = fromJsonFile(path);
if (person.getAge() != Person.DEFAULT_AGE) {
    // do something with the age
}
```

The deserialize method will exactly be the same for both apps (removed redundant if statement though)

```
public static Person fromJsonFile(String path) {
    try (Reader reader = new FileReader(path)) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        return gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```